# jQuery + jQTouch + Prototype

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, jqtouch

I am trying to load jQuery + jQTouch with prototype. However, I get the following error in prototype.js.

this._each is not a function

I am including prototype.js first, then loading jquery.js then noConflict(), then jqTouch.

Is this the right order?

Comment: May I ask why you need both? Not that it's not acceptable to do so, but what does one have that the other doesn't? (I'm assuming you used prototype on your site and saw jqTouch and wanted to you use [then by necessity needed jQuery?])

Comment: I am using magento, and it relies on Prototype, and the problem is that I have to include jQuery for jQTouch. Basically I am skinning Magento with jqtouch and it already uses prototype so both are needed which is really annoying.

Comment: I think I have the solution, but I'll be darned if I can find a simple piece of code to test prototype with. So clunky compared to jQuery--not that I'm biased.

Comment: So I: included jQuery, called $.noConflict(), included jqTouch, then included prototype (then you include Magento). That _should_ work.

Comment: It seems no matter the order it always throws the same error regarding the _each function. It seems that prototype overrides the normal array functions(http://www.prototypejs.org/api/array) and has the ability to use "vanilla" loops which solved on problem but caused a bunch of others so I'm at a loss right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're running into the problem described here:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7809

This patch should make it go away:

http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/4424bda377336342ce04ab5299bf1ce624cdb7b1